# OpenVPN and Routing and IPtables

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

GOAL: Access internal network devices and browse web via the tunnel.

```
192.168.2.x = internal network
192.168.3.x = openvpn server
192.168.2.111 = openvpn server on internal network

[root@openvpn ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.3.2     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.3.0     192.168.3.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

and

```
[root@openvpn ~]# cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf
port 1194 #- port
proto udp #- protocol
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
reneg-sec 0
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login #- Comment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
#plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf #- Uncomment this line if you are using FreeRADIUS
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 5 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status 1194.log
verb 3
```

and

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 18.4.79.28 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
reneg-sec 0
verb 3
```

I can connect just fine and access the VPN box. However, I can not browse the web or access other local network devices.

I have IPTables off. Do I need IP table rules or is my routing off?

I need 192.168.3.0 to access 192.168.2.0 :)

EDIT: 
forgot to mention, I do have this set;

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
```

### EDIT:

I used this:

```
[root@openvpn ~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source <SERVERIP>
[root@openvpn ~]# iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

I GET:

```
pinging 192.168.2.5
reply from 192.168.3.1 destination host unreachable
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two things you'll need to check and potentially fix.

First, you need to ensure that IP forwarding is turned on in the kernel.  IP forwarding allows the kernel to pass packets from one interface to another.  You can check this with the below:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

If you see a `0` instead of a `1`, then you need to enable IP forwarding.  The easiest and most reliable way is to add the following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or modify it if there is already an entry for `net.ipv4.ip_forward`):

```
# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And then run `sysctl -p` to reload the configuration from that file.

Next, you will need to configure `IPtables` to do Network Address Translation (NAT) on the packets coming from the VPN.  Otherwise, when those packets g'et sent out `eth0`, any devices that receive the packets won't know how to talk back (they dont have a route back to `192.168.3.0/24` through the VPN server).  There are two ways you can setup the NAT: Static NAT (SNAT) and Masquerade.  SNAT is recommended when the IP address on the outbound interface (`eth0` in your case) is not expected to change.  Masquerade mode is designed for dynamic IP situations such as dial-up or other dynamically assigned address configurations (cable modems, DSL, etc.).  Both are configured similarly, though.

For SNAT, you would add an IPtables rule along the lines of (note, I used `192.168.2.13` because I don't know the IP you have assigned to eth0; you would want to change that as is appropriate):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.13
```

If the IP address on eth0 is not static and reliable, you would use Masquerade, which would look like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 2):

You do need a iptables rule for the VPN clients to access the network.

First make sure your system allow NAT:

```
# Setup sysctl to enable NAT.
echo "# Allowing nat translation for VPN clients.
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" > "/etc/sysctl.d/openvpn.conf"
# load new sysctl config.
command sysctl -p "/etc/sysctl.d/openvpn.conf" > '/dev/null'
```

Then install the NAT iptables rule for the VPN network:

```
CURRENT_IP_RANGE="192.168.2"
command iptables -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s "${CURRENT_IP_RANGE}.0/24" \
                      -o 'eth0' -j MASQUERADE 2>'/dev/null' \
    || command iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "${CURRENT_IP_RANGE}.0/24" \
                       -o 'eth0' -j MASQUERADE
```

These rules are an extract of [openvpn-tools](https://github.com/biapy/howto.biapy.com/blob/master/openvpn/openvpn-tools), presented in [Install and setup OpenVPN on Debian](https://howto.biapy.com/en/debian-gnu-linux/servers/various/install-and-setup-openvpn-on-debian), a OpenVPN management script and how-to i've written.

Make sure also to have a DNS server accessible from your VPN clients. A simple answer is OpenDNS (8.8.8.8). A more complex, but may-be better solution is to install Bind on the server (this is the solution used by openvpn-tools).

openvpn-tools may be of interest to you as it provide clients configuration exports for various systems and automatize the setup of new VPN networks.

**EDIT for Openvpn 2.x server and 1.5 client**

See: [OpenVPN releases notes](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/release-notes.html).

To get OpenVPN 2.0 to talk with the 1.5/1.6 versions, put this in the 1.x config file:

```
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
key-method 2
```

For TLS usage, key-method 2 is now the default.

Comment: Tried your script, still no luck. Even setup a debian fresh install server

Comment: did you follow my install guide ? i've used it 3 times already without problems.

Comment: also, did you use the --nat and --gateway options: command openvpn-tools --domain="domain.vpn" --gateway='y' --nat='y'

Comment: Yes, I used gateway and nat :(

Comment: hum... did your client connect to the vpn correctly ? what does openvpn-tools -d domain.vpn --status print you ?

Comment: Connects fine and all the required features are enabled. Just a routing issue I'm sure.

Comment: hum.. is eth0 the interface connected to Internet ? If it is another one, you may need to use a little customisation. this is the only lack of openvpn-tools at this time.

Comment: eth0 is the one connected to the inter.

Comment: i'm sorry but i can't help you further. My script is very straight forward and if it does not work, you should look at other sources for the problem than openvpn. Perhaps iptables.. ?

Also make sure your server is 2.3.2 if you are using Ubuntu clients (openvpn 2.3). A 2.2 server with 2.3 clients is a bug prone environment.

Comment: This is the latest version of debian.

Comment: Sorry, i mean OpenVPN 2.3.2 as server. See the prerequisites for my installation guide. You need to backport the OpenVPN version from Debian Testing (and iproute2). The OpenVPN version of Debian 7.0 Wheezy is 2.2.x, that cause problem with Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander clients (among other OpenVPN v2.3 clients). See: https://forums.openvpn.net/topic13080.html

Comment: Client is 1.5.6 and Server is 2.2.1 so could this be a bug issue?

Comment: See my latest edit to my answer. I'll see if openvpn-tools needs an update for this issue.

Comment: Alright, well I just downloaded the latest 2.3 client. I thought I had the latest but apparently not. And wow the interface has really changed.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade your server as well, you should try to use a 2.2 client.

Comment: So server and client need to match up? Is there an easy way to upgrade the server? Or does that have to be done manually

Comment: Client and Server can be of different versions, if there is no bugs affecting them. It is a good practice to have a latest version server, as it provice security enhancements and new functionnalities while being retrocompatible. For the server upgrade, in the prerequisites of my OpenVPN installation guide, i've given a link to a Debian backport howto that is quite straight forward: https://howto.biapy.com/en/debian-gnu-linux/system/software/backport-a-debian-package-from-testing-to-stable

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are using AWS, but please make sure that you **disable destination/source checking** on any AWS instance you may be using to run this.

Right click on the instance, mouse over to Network, then there should be an option there.

If this doesn't help you, hope it helps someone else.

Comment: somehow i found this answer, the openvpn must be setup like a nat http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck ... thanks @lobi

Comment: THANK YOU! All the other answers I could find suggested using NAT on the OpenVPN server which is an ugly and unnecessary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you should try to use standard routing instead of using NAT (between the internal network and the openvpn network). NAT should be your last option.

The "edge router" (probably your CPE) (bewteen your internal network and the rest of internet) needs to send the packets for the VPN nodes (in 192.168.3.0/24) to the Open server. You have to add a route like this in the edge-router/CPE :

```
# This is the Linux command, find the equivalent for your router:
ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.2.111
```

Now this router may be a combo FAI-provided xDSL-model+router so you may not be able to do this.

If you cannot do this (you cannot add routes on your router) and if your edge router thinks your internal nerwork is 192.168.0.0/16 (or at least contains 192.168.3.0/34) you can setup an ARP proxy in eth0 for the VPN nodes in the main network :

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$xx/proxy_arp
```

with x=eth0, x=tun0, x=all (I don't really know in which interface you should set this option).

This ideas is that your OpenVPN server will answer ARP requests on the eth0 netrwork for the nodes in the VPN. It will only work is your router thinks that 192.168.3.0/24 is in the internal network : othetrwise, it will not send an ARP requests on the internal network.